# SQLite - Convert Table Array?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to convert 3 columns from an SQLite table to 3 arrays. I have the current code to get the DB:

```
sqlite3 *db; char *error;
int rc;
rc = sqlite3_open("db.sql", &db);
if (rc)
{
    cout << "Error Connecting";
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
else {
    char **results = NULL;
    int rows, columns;
    const char *sqlSelect = "SELECT name, surname, dob FROM data";
    sqlite3_get_table(db, sqlSelect, &results, &rows, &columns, &error);
    if (rc) {
        system("color 0c");
        cout << "Error executing query";
    }
    else {
    // What to put here?
    }
}
```

I am having trouble continuing, the documentation is a little hard for me to understand. How can I convert my array 'results' to something useful? (etc 3 arrays, dobs[] names[] surnames[])

Comment: fwiw; the get_table api is maintained for backwards compatibility, you should use newer methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 3 elements of `results` contain the field names. After that they are the records, one field at a time.

For example:

```
results[0] = "name";
results[1] = "surname";
results[2] = "dob";
results[3] = "John";
results[4] = "Doe";
results[5] = "01/01/1970";
// etc...
```

So you want to skip the first 3 results, and then put the remainder into containers.
Don't use arrays. Put them in 3 vectors:

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
std::vector<std::string> surnames;
std::vector<std::string> dobs;

for (int i = 2; i < rows; i += 3) {
    names.push_back(results[i]);
    surnames.push_back(results[i + 1]);
    dobs.push_back(results[i + 2]);
}
```

Comment: Namespace std has no member 'vector'?

Comment: You need to `#include <vector>` (and `<string>`.)